# Why are bootstrap margins so huge, 15px at both sides, summary 30px?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, margins

Why not a 5px width, or 10 pixels, why just exactly fifteen.
What is this digit based on? Someone? Any idea? Help Please!

Answer (score 0):

you can override the size of that margin. place some css on the begining of your code. inside style tag.

```
<style>
.class {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px
}
</style>
```

Comment: I know but, every bootstrap *.PSD templete contains that margin, or a "glutter"

Comment: Is it was done because we hold the phone in our palm, and big margins created to prevent unintended clicking text by the hand on the sides?